# Getting decimal values from SQL Server database

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a dataset that contains decimal values pulled from a database, when I try to assign the values in it to variables, the decimal values somehow got rounded to a whole number. I have manually ran the query which selects a column of decimal(18,4) datatype and verified that the output contains decimal places. During the breakpoint, I also found out that the (dtr(c.ColumnName)) actually becomes an integer.

Please kindly advice thanks.

```
 Dim bannerValsAmt(1) As Decimal
        Dim bannerVals(1) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim ds As DataSet = LoadBanner()
        For Each dtr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            For Each c As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns
                If i = 0 Then
                    bannerValsAmt(0) = CType((dtr(c.ColumnName)), Decimal)
                ElseIf i = 1 Then
                    bannerVals(0) = (dtr(c.ColumnName)).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf i = 2 Then
                    bannerValsAmt(1) = CType((dtr(c.ColumnName)), Decimal)
                ElseIf i = 3 Then
                    bannerVals(1) = (dtr(c.ColumnName)).ToString.Trim
                End If
                i += 1
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Decimal data type isn't floating point.  If you do not specify any decimal places, then you don't get any.

Comment: As an aside, when working with DataRows, I find the following syntax easier to read:   bannerValsAmt(0) = dtr.Field(Of Decimal)(c.ColumnName)

Comment: can you post your query, I think your query returns integer.